# Generate Buttons inside Wrap from List<String> flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `List<String>` and I want to generate, inside a `Wrap` widget, N `Buttons` (N string lenght).

I read about a `List.generate`, I'm trying to implement it, do you know how I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
Wrap(
    children:buttons.map((s)=>
                        MaterialButton(
                          //shape,color etc...
                        onPressed:(){
                          //todo
                        },
                          child:Text(s)
                        )).toList()
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way :

```
List<Widget> _ButtonsList(){
  List<String> list = _getLanguages(); 
  List listings = new List<Widget>();
  int lenght = list.length;
  for (int i=0;i<=lenght; i++){
    listings.add(_getrandomButton(list[i]));
  }
return listings;
}

Widget _myWrap(){
Wrap(
 spacing: 12,
 children: _ButtonsList(),
);
}
```

But it said me that I called `list.split` on `null`

```
Future<String> _read(String filename) async {
  try {
  final file = await _localFile(filename);

// Read the file.
return await file.readAsString();
} catch (e) {
// If encountering an error, return 0.
return "Can't read";
 }
}

String _myRead( String filename){
var _bio;

_read(filename).then((String) {
  _bio = String;
 });
 return _bio;
}

List<String> _getLanguages() {
 String _bio= _myRead("bio.txt");
 List<String> list =_bio.split(",");
 return list;
}
```

This is what I have inside `"bio.txt"` :
    English,Italian,Chinese

Answer (score 0):

First, create your buttons:

```
final strings = ['A', 'B'];
final buttons = List<Widget>.generate(
  strings.length,
  (i) => RaisedButton(
    onPressed: null,
    child: Text(strings[i]),
  ),
).toList();
```

And then use them directly as `Wrap`'s children:

```
Wrap(children: buttons)
```